# Is there a real need to adopt ssl transport layer in a microservice architecture for internal lan-only Service to Service communication?

Tags: ssl, https, microservices

In a scenario where there are thousands of webservices are there reasons to use also a signed cert for each microservice or it's just going to add overhead? Services communicate via VPC sitting behind a firewall while Public endpoints are behind a nginx public facing a valid CA cert.

Services are on multiple servers on aws.

Comment: One certificate per host is all you need, not one per service.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From my limited experience, I believe that it is overkill. If an attacker has access to listen in or interact with your internal network then there are most likely other issues which you should be contending with.

This article on [auth0.com](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/09/13/an-introduction-to-microservices-part-2-API-gateway/) explains the use of SSL only on connections to the external client. I also share this view and believe implementing SSL at an individual service level would get extremely difficult unless you where running some form of proxy such as HAProxy or Nginx on each individual host which is sub-optimal, especially if you're using a form of managed cluster like Kubernetes or Docker Swarm.

My current thoughts are its fine to run SSL just for your edge services, ensure you lock down your AWS network using something like [Scout2](https://isecpartners.github.io/Scout2/) and run unencrypted for inter-service communication on your lan.

Comment: With HTTP2 pretty much requiring ssl, and being faster then http- is this still a valid answer? From a security point of view, perhaps, but what about from a technical and optimization point of view?

Answer (score 1):

unless all intranet in the cloud are fully VLAN-configured and isolated, is it possible for other hosts that you don't own that are on the same LAN to steal your password by running a simple tcpdump? if that's the case, we need ssl or other encryption internally on the cloud too.